# R:data simulation

Tags: r, simulation

I am m trying to run the following code:

```
data_greene<-read.delim(file.choose(),header=T)
result_b2_HC0<-matrix(1:2000,ncol=4)
for (i in 1:500){
  X1<-data_greene[[3]]*10^-4
  X2<-X1^2
  e<-rnorm(50,0,1)
  sigma2<-exp(5.30+5.30*X1)
  lambda<-max(sigma2)/min(sigma2)
  Y<-1+1*X1+0*X2+sqrt(sigma2)*e
  lms<-lmsreg(Y~X1+X2)
  yhat<-lms$fitted
  resid<-lms$residual
  s<-abs(resid)
  lms2<-lmsreg(s~yhat)
  shat<-lms2$fitted
  w1<-1/shat^2
  scale<-lms$scale[1]       
  stdres<-resid/scale

  e=abs(stdres)
  w2<-NULL
  for (i in 1:50){
    if(e[i]<=1.345) w2[i]<-1 else w2[i]<-1.345/e[i]
  }

  w<-w1*w2

  WLS<-lm(Y~X1+X2,weights=w)
  res1<-WLS$residual

  HCCMEHC0<-function(Y,X1,X2){
    X<-cbind(1,X1,X2)
    W<-diag(w)
    inv<-solve(t(X)%*%W%*%X)
    psi0<-diag(res1^2)
    HC0<-inv%*%t(X)%*%W%*%psi0%*%W%*%X%*%inv
    return(HC0)
  }
  result_b2_HC0[i,1]<-WLS$coef[3]
  result_b2_HC0[i,2]<-sqrt(HCCMEHC0(Y,X1,X2)[3,3])
  result_b2_HC0[i,3]<-result_b2_HC0[i,1]/result_b2_HC0[i,2]
  result_b2_HC0[i,4]<-2*pt(-abs(result_b2_HC0[i,3]),df=47)
}
result_b2_HC0
```

I would expect the matrix to be complete, but the result only appears at row 50 in the matrix. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should check your variable `i` which is used in the first loop and in a nested of one.

Comment: Could you give some indication what type of data you are using. Q. Is there a problem with the files themselves?

Comment: this would be much easier to sift through if you fixed your spacebar

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same variable `i` in two nested for loops. Change the second for loop to use the variable `j` instead.

To avoid this error, make sure you always use indentation. Also, learn how to use vector mathematics. Your second loop can be rewritten from

```
e=abs(stdres)
w2<-NULL
for (i in 1:50){
  if(e[i]<=1.345) w2[i]<-1 else w2[i]<-1.345/e[i]
}
```

to

```
e=abs(stdres)
w2<-ifelse( e <= 1.345, 1, 1.345/e )
```

This is cleaner, easier to read, and faster.